# Distorted drop-down list inside an HTML table

Tags: html, html-table, html-lists

I want to design a form which consists of a table that has a text-box and a drop-down list. When I add the drop-down list, the form gets distorted. I have these problems: 
1) list is so wide. I need to make its width fits the widest text.
2) Also the height of the cells somehow increased.

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body id="body">   

<div id="wrapper">
<table align='center' cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="data_table" border=1>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Type</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="text-field"></td>

        <td><select name="D1">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        </select> </td>
<td><input type="button" class="add" id="submit-button" value="Add Row"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**NOTE:** There is a third column not shown in the image. It contains a button as shown in the code.

Comment: please share your code

Comment: @Chris I did now.

Comment: Hey, I just have tried your code in **[jsBin](http://jsbin.com/yijofihawa/edit?html,js,output)** and there is nothing wrong with it. It must be an issue with css, can you share your css code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the header  of your table. You have 2 columns in the first row and 3 columns in the second row.

To keep symmetry use the following standardized code:

```
<thead> 
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="text-field">
        </td>

        <td>
            <select name="D1">
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            </select> 
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" class="add" id="submit-button" value="Add Row">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image]

[image]

What I have done is, I added standard  and  of HTML table, and added 3rd column in the header Action. You can rename it according to your need.

You will have to check your CSS as well. It might effect the form you have created!